# Elasticsearch 1.7 на Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть развернутое приложение на Heroku с установленным аддоном *Bonsai Elasticsearch*, где по умолчанию версия 6.5.4

Но сейчас мне потребовалось изменить версию Elasticsearch на старенькую 1.7, как я могу это сделать?

[image: Bonsai Elasticsearch]

Comment: В первую очередь они не обратносовместимы и если вы работаете с эластиком через его `API`, то думаю понимаете, что код будет не рабочим, но если это не повод чтобы не делать этого, тогда просто качайте dist эластика с архива и дейплойте вместо этого. 

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-7-0

если вы имели ввиду или можно как-то `просто` изменить версию в конфугирации, тогда нет. так не можно. только заново инсталировать.

Comment: @raviga Здравствуй. Можешь, пожалуйста, расписать подробнее, как задеплоить скачанный эластик? На локалке у меня как раз использовался скачанный 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После общения с поддержкой Bonsai, выянил, что старую версию могут предоставить, если оформить план Бизнес кластера (800$/mo).

Моё решение - залить на удаленный сервер Elasticsearch нужной версии, посадить его на открытый порт для доступа извне, и передать *сервер:порт* через Config Vars Heroku.